# Why can't I type or delete my code in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner programmer using vscode on my journey. I use an M1 MacBook(not pro). I use the latest version of vscode as well! I was coding a game using the module pygame and for some reason, when I did command + C, there was this whitespace that popped up in vscode. I selected some code, copied it(using command+c) and this whitespace popped up. I tried restarting vscode,opening a new file but the same result. Is there something wrong with my installation or is this a bug? Could this be something wrong with the Python extension?

[image: Proof of whitespace]

If you view this image, you will see a white space and it doesn't allow me to delete any of my code and isn't allowing me to type either. I'm able to select pieces of code but I'm not able to do anything else. This doesn't just happen with command+c, it happens with anything with ctrl, command and some other key code. I went to check my key bindings and I don't see anything wrong with it.

[image: Key Bindings Image]

I'm not sure what to call what just happened. I tried to figure out what happened, but I have no idea of what went wrong. Is there a way I can get rid of this feature in vscode? It has slowed down my programming process very much.

Comment: Do you have any vs code extensions installed?

Comment: I have Jupyter, Jupiter Keymap, Jupiter Notebook Renderers, Pylance, Python, and vim!

Comment: Vim is probably the issue here. Try disabling it or uninstalling it.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!